# transform irregular timeseries into zscores relative to closest neighbors

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a time series with an irregularly spaced index.  I want to transform the data by subtracting a mean and dividing by a standard deviation for every point.  However, I only want to calculate the means and standard deviations using those data values that are a predefined time distance away.  In my example below, I used regularly spaced distances but I want this to accommodate irregular ones as well.

For example:

```
n = 20
ts = pd.Series(np.random.rand(n),
               pd.date_range('2014-05-01', periods=n, freq='T', name='Time'))
```

Lets say I want the zscore for each point relative to all points within one minute of that point.

The final result should look like the following series.

```
Time
2014-05-01 00:00:00    0.707107
2014-05-01 00:01:00   -0.752435
2014-05-01 00:02:00    0.866662
2014-05-01 00:03:00   -0.576136
2014-05-01 00:04:00   -0.580471
2014-05-01 00:05:00   -0.253403
2014-05-01 00:06:00   -0.076657
2014-05-01 00:07:00    1.054413
2014-05-01 00:08:00    0.095783
2014-05-01 00:09:00   -1.030982
2014-05-01 00:10:00    1.041127
2014-05-01 00:11:00   -1.028084
2014-05-01 00:12:00    0.198363
2014-05-01 00:13:00    0.851951
2014-05-01 00:14:00   -1.152701
2014-05-01 00:15:00    1.070238
2014-05-01 00:16:00   -0.395849
2014-05-01 00:17:00   -0.968585
2014-05-01 00:18:00    0.077004
2014-05-01 00:19:00    0.707107
Freq: T, dtype: float64
```

Comment: time window based rolling will be in 0.19.0, see http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#rolling-are-now-time-series-aware; merged recently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something I've been working on.  Keep in mind this is related to but different than (as I suspect you know, otherwise you probably wouldn't be asking the question) pandas `rolling` feature.  For your the regularly spaced data you gave, it would tie out pretty well and we can use that to compare.

What I'll do is use `np.subtract.outer` to compute the distances of all items in a series with itself.

Assume we have your time series `ts`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 20
np.random.seed([3,1415])
data = np.random.rand(n)
tidx = pd.date_range('2014-05-01', periods=n, freq='T', name='Time')
#                                                   ^
#                                                   |
#                                            Minute Frequency
ts = pd.Series(data, tidx, name='Bliggles')
```

Now I can use the time index to calculate distaces like so

```
distances = pd.DataFrame(np.subtract.outer(tidx, tidx), tidx, tidx).abs()
```

From here, I test what is less than a desired distance. Say that distance is called `delta`

```
lt_delta = (distances <= delta).stack()
lt_delta = lt_delta[lt_delta]
```

Finally, I take the values from the index of `lt_delta` and find what the corresponding values were in `ts`

```
pd.Series(ts.ix[lt_delta.index.to_series().str.get(1)].values, lt_delta.index)
```

I return a `groupby` object so it looks and feels like calling `rolling`.  When I wrap it in a function, it looks like

### Super Function

```
def groupbydelta(ts, delta):
    tidx = ts.index
    distances = pd.DataFrame(np.subtract.outer(tidx, tidx), tidx, tidx).abs()

    lt_delta = (distances <= delta).stack()
    lt_delta = lt_delta[lt_delta]
    closest = pd.Series(ts.ix[lt_delta.index.to_series().str.get(1)].values, lt_delta.index)

    return closest.groupby(level=0)
```

#### Inspired by root's answer, I wrote an improved pandas/numpy solution.

```
def groupbydelta(ts, delta):
    tidx = ts.index
    iv = pd.DataFrame({'lo': tidx - delta, 'hi': tidx + delta}, tidx)
    return pd.concat([ts.loc[r.lo:r.hi] for i, r in iv.iterrows()],
                     keys=iv.index).groupby(level=0)
```

Let's test it out.  I'll use a `delta=pd.Timedelta(1, 'm')` (that's one minute).  For the time series I created, for every date time index, I should see that index, the minute prior, and the minute after.  This should be equivalent to `ts.rolling(3, center=True)` with the exceptions at the edges.  I'll do both and compare.

```
gbdelta = groupbydelta(ts, pd.Timedelta(1, 'm')).mean()
rolling = ts.rolling(3, center=True).mean()

pd.concat([gbdelta, rolling], axis=1, keys=['Delta', 'Rolling']).head()
```

[image]

That looks great!  Difference between the two being that `rolling` has `NaN` at the edges while `gbdelta` doesn't require a specific number of elements, but that was by design.

What about irregular indices?

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
n = 7200
data = np.random.rand(n)
tidx = (pd.to_datetime(['2013-02-06']) + np.random.rand(n) * pd.Timedelta(1, 'd'))
irregular_series = pd.Series(data, tidx, name='Sketch').sort_index()
```

And plot the `irregular_series` and some filtered versions based on closest neighbors.

[image]

But you asked for zscores:

```
zd = (irregular_series - gbirr.mean()) / gbirr.std()
```

This z-scoring is a bit tricky.  I had to find the grouped means and standard deviations and then use them with the original series.  I'm still thinking about a smother way.  But that's smooth enough.

What does it look like?

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, figsize=[10, 5])
irregular_series.plot(style='.', ax=axes[0], title='Original')
zd.plot(style='.', ax=axes[1], title='Z-Scored')
```

[image]

---

#### Answer

Finally, you asked about the z-score for your data example.  To ensure I got the right answer...

```
gbd = groupbydelta(ts, pd.Timedelta(1, 'm'))

ts.sub(gbd.mean()).div(gbd.std())

Time
2014-05-01 00:00:00    0.707107
2014-05-01 00:01:00   -0.752435
2014-05-01 00:02:00    0.866662
2014-05-01 00:03:00   -0.576136
2014-05-01 00:04:00   -0.580471
2014-05-01 00:05:00   -0.253403
2014-05-01 00:06:00   -0.076657
2014-05-01 00:07:00    1.054413
2014-05-01 00:08:00    0.095783
2014-05-01 00:09:00   -1.030982
2014-05-01 00:10:00    1.041127
2014-05-01 00:11:00   -1.028084
2014-05-01 00:12:00    0.198363
2014-05-01 00:13:00    0.851951
2014-05-01 00:14:00   -1.152701
2014-05-01 00:15:00    1.070238
2014-05-01 00:16:00   -0.395849
2014-05-01 00:17:00   -0.968585
2014-05-01 00:18:00    0.077004
2014-05-01 00:19:00    0.707107
Freq: T, dtype: float64
```

---

#### Timing

Inspired by root's answer I rewrote my function to be interval based.  It made sense that it would be more efficient than finding the outer difference for certain length time series.

*code*

```
def pirsquared(ts, delta):
    gbd = groupbydelta(ts, delta)
    return ts.sub(gbd.mean()).div(gbd.std())

cols = ['pirsquared', 'root']
ts_len = [500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]
dt_len = [1, 5, 10, 20]
summary = pd.DataFrame([], pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ts_len, dt_len], names=['Points', 'Delta']), cols)
for n in ts_len:
    for d in dt_len:
        np.random.seed([3,1415])
        data = np.random.rand(n)
        tidx = (pd.to_datetime(['2013-02-06']) + np.random.rand(n) * pd.Timedelta(1, 'd'))
        ts = pd.Series(data, tidx, name='Sketch').sort_index()
        delta = pd.Timedelta(d, 'm')
        pt = timeit(lambda: pirsquared(ts, delta), number=2) / 2
        rt = timeit(lambda: root(ts, delta), number=2) / 2
        summary.loc[(n, d), cols] = pt, rt

summary.unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! `A` for effort.  I need a while to process this.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a `pandas`/`numpy` solution but should give decent performance.  Essentially, to find closest points you can build an [Interval Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) using the [`intervaltree`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree) package on PyPI.

The `intervaltree` package is fairly simple to use, and is syntactically quite similar to a dictionary.  One thing to keep in mind with this package is that upper bounds are not included in intervals, so you'll need to pad the upper bounds when building the tree.  Note in my code below that I add an extra nanosecond to the upper bound.

```
import intervaltree

def get_ts_zscore(ts, delta):
    # Get the upper and lower bounds, padding the upper bound.
    lower = ts.index - delta
    upper = ts.index + delta +  pd.Timedelta(1, 'ns')

    # Build the interval tree.
    t = intervaltree.IntervalTree().from_tuples(zip(lower, upper, ts))

    # Extract the overlaping data points for each index value.
    ts_grps = [[iv.data for iv in t[idx]]for idx in ts.index]

    # Compute the z-scores.
    ts_data = [(x - np.mean(grp))/np.std(grp, ddof=1) for x, grp in zip(ts, ts_grps)]

    return pd.Series(ts_data, ts.index)
```

I'm not able to replicate your exact expected output, maybe due to how I'm randomly generating the data?  My output exactly matches what I get running @piRSquared's code though, so I'm pretty sure it's right.

**Timings**

Timings on the sample data (`n=20`):

```
%timeit get_ts_zscore(ts, pd.Timedelta(1, 'm'))

100 loops, best of 3: 2.89 ms per loop


%%timeit
gbd = groupbydelta(ts, pd.Timedelta(1, 'm'))
ts.sub(gbd.mean()).div(gbd.std())

100 loops, best of 3: 7.13 ms per loop
```

Timings on larger data (`n=10**4`):

```
%timeit get_ts_zscore(ts, pd.Timedelta(1, 'm'))

1 loops, best of 3: 1.44 s per loop


%%timeit
gbd = groupbydelta(ts, pd.Timedelta(1, 'm'))
ts.sub(gbd.mean()).div(gbd.std())

1 loops, best of 3: 5.92 s per loop
```

Comment: Outstanding!  I'll look into that. +1

Comment: Thanks @root.  I needed a pandas/numpy solution but I'm sure this will help others.

Comment: I rewrote my function and ran some additional timeits.  I thought you might find it interesting.